# Angular: Adding an import to app.module.ts throws an error

Tags: angular

I thought that if you add an import to the controller.ts file, that it had to be added to app.module.ts as well. But, when I added the NgForm to my controller alone without adding it to app.module.ts my code worked fine. Then when I added it to app.module.ts I got an error. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer at a different forum: If your controller.ts is part of a module that is added in app.module.ts then it doesn't need to have that import.